# Swift 3 - Generic File Opener

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, file, alamofire

Good Day

I'm not new to swift but im new to the way swift handles file's etc... 
Ok ive done some extensive googling and stacking but I cant find a solution or an answer that matches my requirements.

We have a system that users can upload files on the web. The extensions are as follows:

.pdf .txt .doc .docx .bmp
.jpeg .jpg .png .gif .tiff
.tif .mp4 .avi .flv .mov
.mwv .m4v .m4p .mpg .mpeg
.mpv .3gp .xls .xlsx .xlsm
.xlsb

Ok so Swift is downloading the files and saving to the local storage. I can retrieve the path once downloaded.

**What I want to achieve is opening the file in the app and it must be able to do this according to the file type** eg: image opens as image, video as vid ,etc

So my question is do i need to try cater for every file or is there a generic file opener that will open the file accordingly.

The file is downloaded through Alamofire's download function.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use webView to preview your files.

Comment: would a webview cater for all the extensions?

Comment: web view can handle most of these extensions

Comment: I don't believe a web view would work for Microsoft Office files - .doc, .xls etc. It would work for many of the extensions, but not all. Otherwise there is no built in way I am aware of. (I have recently done something very similar and had to cater for every type of file)

Comment: Much appreciated Jack C. I will try the webview and then see what is left

Comment: @LloydHendricks check my answer

Answer (score 1):

There couple of things is available

**Look at using the Quick Look Framework** - [Source](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/UsingtheQuickLookFramework.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010413-SW1)

A Quick Look preview controller can display previews for the following items:

1. iWork documents
2. Microsoft Office documents (Office ‘97 and newer)
3. Rich Text Format (RTF) documents
4. PDF files
5. Images
6. Text files whose uniform type identifier (UTI) conforms to the
   public.text type (see Uniform Type Identifiers Reference)
7. Comma-separated value (csv) files

**WebView**
Supported File Formats are From [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview)

> In addition to HTML content, UIWebView objects can be used to display
>   other content types, such as Keynote, PDF, and Pages documents.

From [Apple Technical Q&A QA1630](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1630/_index.html)

1. Excel (.xls)
2. Keynote (.key.zip)
3. Numbers (.numbers.zip)
4. Pages (.pages.zip)
5. PDF (.pdf)
6. Powerpoint (.ppt)
7. Word (.doc)

Comment: Thanks will look at it and give it a try